# Add Dynamic Variable to Paypal Donation button

Tags: c#, paypal

I want to add a dynamic variable to Paypal Donate button
This is my Simple Paypal Code

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XX">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/IL/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

I Try add hidden field with my variable and I cant see this variable when entering to my Paypal account.

Also try to add static variable, but cant see this variable on "My recent Activity"
[image]

How can i pass dynamic data to paypal donate button and see those variable on my account

thanks

Comment: you would assign the value using some code behind or javascript function can you show your code behind..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add any field you want.  When adding custom data you would have to use the actual custom parameter...it's literally called custom.  You can put whatever you want in it up to 256 characters.

That said, when working with a hosted button you may not be able to include the custom parameter in the HTML button code directly.  Instead, you would have to put it where you're showing in your screenshot while building the button, but then of course you can't make it dynamic.

If you really need to work with dynamic data in your payment option(s) I would recommend switching to the Express Checkout API instead of using PayPal Standard buttons.

Another option would be to simply uncheck the "save at PayPal" option in the button creation wizard, which would make the button a non-hosted button so you could add your own parameters to it directly, and then you could make them dynamic.  Of course this option isn't as secure as a hosted button or Express Checkout, though.

Comment: I add my value in hidden field with name custom, and its resolve my problem.